Why Haskell Language Server extension in VSCode doesn't recognize module when importing it?

Why it highlights Data.MultiSet?
package.yaml:
name: anagram
version: 1.4.0.8

dependencies:
  - base
  - multiset
  - text
  - containers

library:
  exposed-modules: Anagram
  source-dirs: src
  ghc-options: -Wall

tests:
  test:
    main: Tests.hs
    source-dirs: test
    dependencies:
      - anagram
      - hspec

A program compiles fine and passes tests with stack test.
I tried to restart HLS in many ways. May be I don't know the correct one.
Versions:

stack 2.15.5
stack resolver: lts-20.25
ghc 9.8.2
cabal 3.10.3.0
HLS 2.7.0.0


Here is the answer to the question: https://discourse.haskell.org/t/haskell-language-server-doesnt-recognise-installed-modules/5894/5
In short, cabal should be in the root of opened VSCode project.
